# How do I load data from my SQLite DB into Rstudio?

Tags: r, sqlite

I created a database with SQL for a schoolproject. Currently I'm stuck at importing this data into rstudio. I put my DB file in this directory: /Users/milanpatty/Documents/Business/Semester_2/R/Proftaak". When I tried to make a connection with this code:

```
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = 'Festivate.db')
```

I got this error:

```
Warning message:
Couldn't set synchronous mode: file is not a database
Use `synchronous` = NULL to turn off this warning.
```

BTW I use DB browser as an interface for SQLite. Could anybody help me with this problem?

edit: I installed the library RSQLite in R

Comment: Is the directory you put it n your current R working directory? Check that it matches the value of `getwd()`. How did you create `Festivate.db` originally?

Comment: Was that file created by SQLite? The file extension alone doesn't mean it's a sqlite3 database. Try `readBin("foo.db", raw(), n=6)`; if it returns `[1] 53 51 4c 69 74 65` then it is most like a legit SQLite file ... if not, then it isn't. (BTW: `rawToChar(...)` is `"SQLite"`. If you go further, say `rawToChar(readBin(...,n=15))`, then you might see `"SQLite format 3"`.)

Comment: @MrFlick my working directory is fine. I created the file originally in Azure data studio. The reason why I started working here is for the database connection. Rstudio does not support a connection with Azure data studio and since I'm on Mac I can't use Microsoft's SQL Server Management System.

Comment: @r2evans I checked the file extension with your method and it says that it's a XML file. In DB browser for SQLite I can choose between CSV, JSON and SQL as export format. I chose for the SQL file but it doesn't not work right now.

Comment: I don't know what DB browser you're talking about, but perhaps that's more an issue for "Tech Support" for this. It doesn't seem to be about programming. (If it is going to be XML, though, you could consider using the `xml2` package to read it.)

Comment: I already fixed the problem. Had something to do with the file format. Saved my database from DB Browser for SQLite and this time it was a valid database.